# Asp.Net: Debug website in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, debugging

Is it possible to debug an Asp.Net website running on iis?
I am able to debug an Asp.Net web application project, but not a web site, and wanted to know if this is by design or am I missing something.

Comment: When you **Attach** to the IIS worker process do you get anything in the **Output** window?

Answer (score 17):

Had this same problem. The key is to not open the project using the visual studio project file.

1. In IIS, under your Default Web Site, you need to have already created an application, and pointed it at the folder containing the files.
2. In Visual Studio, go to File > Open > Web Site (Shift+Alt+O).
3. Select the newly-created application.
4. You'll notice the solution explorer now uses the URL in place of the project name. (http://localhost/mysite/)
5. Click the debug arrow like normal.

Comment: So much of the same answers over the internet. This is the only 1 I have been looking for

Answer (score 4):

you can attached the asp_wp into your Visual Studio debuggar to debug it.

Comment: it works find for web application but breakpoint does not stop for website

Comment: @Yaron Naveh - you need pdb files near the dlls, also to leverage more debug features build your site in debug mode.

Comment: I'm using "website" not "web application". It does not compile locally but only on the fly in iis. How can I create the pdb?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

1. Compile project in Debug mode.
2. Set debug="true" in the web.config.
3. Attach to IIS working process (which v of IIS do you use?) (Ctrl-Alt-P in VS). There can be MANY processes. **MAKE SURE YOU ATTACH TO THE CORRECT ONE**.

Comment: I use iis 5.
There is only one process.
I use website and not "web project" - it is compiled on the fly so I can't control it.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me. You just copy the files over to the IIS folder, set IIS up and go. (If on the same machine). Make sure your project properties specify "Custom web server" and "http://localhost" (or whatever).

On Vista you need to be running Visual Studio as an Administrator.

If you're running your IIS on a different machine, you'll need to install the Remote Debugger which is on your Visual Studio disks and connect to hat by using Debug|Attach To Process in Visual Studio.

Comment: it works find for web application but breakpoint does not stop for website